# Ggsurvplot doesn't work and the basic plot of the survival curve shows the cumulative hazard plot instead

Tags: r, ggplot2, analysis, survival, hazard

for a project I'm conducting a survival analysis in R on two datasets analysing how much survival time depends on some blood biomarkers; one was used for development and one for validation.

The problem is **when I try to launch the plots of the survival curves, ggsurvplot doesn't work, giving me the error** "*Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 174, 0, 348*". **Also if I launch the object survfit with a normal plot, it gives me a cumulative hazard plot instead** (??).
This problem is present for both datasets equally, so in the following code I'll report the comands just for the first one.

**THE DATA ARE AVAILABLE FOR DOWNLOAD AT THIS LINK**:
https://www.cancerdata.org/resource/doi:10.17195/candat.2016.04.1

WHAT I TRIED TO DO TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM AND DIDN'T WORK:

- Remove all NA values.
- Trying not to set chr's variables as factors (but even so, survfit requires the status variable as a logical or numeric. Also setting it as numeric makes all the observations of Status become NAs).

HERE IS THE CODE I WROTE SO FAR:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(corrplot)
library(readxl)

# development dataset (sheet 1 of 2 of the xlsx document)
dati_D = read_excel("carvalho-prognostic-biomarkers-NSCLC.xlsx", sheet=2)

# renaming some variables' names because of backspace in names
colnames(dati_D)[colnames(dati_D) == "Lymph nodes"] = "LymphNodes"
colnames(dati_D)[colnames(dati_D) == "RT Protocol"] = "RTProtocol"
colnames(dati_D)[colnames(dati_D) == "Total dose (1st)"] = "TotalDose1st"
colnames(dati_D)[colnames(dati_D) == "Total Dose (2nd)"] = "TotalDose2nd"
colnames(dati_D)[colnames(dati_D) == "IL 6"] = "IL6"
colnames(dati_D)[colnames(dati_D) == "IL 8"] = "IL8"
colnames(dati_D)[colnames(dati_D) == "Cyfra 21-1"] = "Cyfra211"
colnames(dati_D)[colnames(dati_D) == "WHO-PS"] = "WHOPS"
colnames(dati_D)[colnames(dati_D) == "CA-9"] = "CA9"
colnames(dati_D)[colnames(dati_D) == "FEV1s%"] = "FEV1s"

# setting chr's as factors
dati_D$Status = as.factor(dati_D$Status)
dati_D$histology = as.factor(dati_D$histology)
dati_D$stage = as.factor(dati_D$stage)
dati_D$Gender = as.factor(dati_D$Gender)
dati_D$RT_Protocol = as.factor(dati_D$RTProtocol)
str(dati_D)

# Survival curves
c1 = survfit(Surv(Survival, Status) ~ Gender, data = dati_D)
plot(c1) # it gives a cumulative hazard plot, why?
ggsurvplot(c1, data = dati_D) # it gives the error mentioned above, why?
```

Please help me identify and solve this issue, because of this I can't keep doing the analysis.
Thank you in advance.

As I wrote above, I tried removing all NAs and not setting qualitative variables as factors, but that didn't work. The dataset is 182x21 so I really don't know what those numbers in the error refer to nor how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!

the problem was that the variable Status had the values “alive” and “dead” instead of 0 and 1.
Change them to these solved the issue.

I leave this here in case anyone will run into a similar problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community : see if my answer addresses your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

One starts by downloading the file:

```
download.file("https://www.cancerdata.org/system/files/publications/carvalho-prognostic-biomarkers-NSCLC.xlsx?file=1&type=node&id=64&force=",destfile="dat1.xlsx")
# Then read from the working directory which happened to be "~/"
#Note the need to name the `sheet` argument and choose the second sheet
dati_D = read_excel("~/dat1.xlsx", sheet=2)
# Then examine the result
str(dati_D)
# Which shows that the Status variable is "alive" or "dead"
dati_D$logical_status <- dati_D$Status == "dead"
#The survival::Surv function assumes 1 (TRUE) is dead

c1 = survfit(Surv(Survival, logical_status) ~ Gender, data = dati_D)
plot(c1) # it gives a cumulative hazard plot, why?
ggsurvplot(c1, data = dati_D)
```

[image]